# Linked server is slower in one server compared to other

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to fetch data from two SQL Servers through linked servers. One is SQL 2014 Express and another is SQL 2008 Standard. But now the 2008 Standard edition is faster than 2014 Express edition.

They base server (from where I am trying to get data) is SQL 2008 R2 Standard.

Is there any reason for that? How to tune that?

Please reply.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to directly answer your questions, as there can be many reasons for this. Off the top of my head:

- Are you using the same query to fetch the data from both servers? If so, are the query plans identical? What happens if you simply read all records from a table without any filters or joins?
- Are the servers located on different parts of the network? (Firewall, load-balancer, etc.)
- How are the databases on the remote servers configured? Multiple data files, etc.? Remember SQL Express has some limitations regarding number of cores in use, etc.
- What are the specs of the remote servers? Does one have faster disks or more RAM than the other? Faster network interface? etc.
- Are the servers busy with other tasks?
- Are the servers virtual or physical?

The best advice I can give for now, is that you should try to examine the remote servers closely. Perhaps run your queries locally on each server, to find out how they perform directly on that server (to eliminate network concerns). Then, maybe try to import the data through SSIS, instead of using Linked servers (to eliminate some linked server configuration concerns). Take baby steps, and little by little, the problem should become more apparent.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan. I have checked the query (same ofcourse) are running fine on local servers and both remote servers are same except one has 2008 Standard and another has 2014 Express. Execution plans are also same. So could not expedite the issue.

Comment: Sounds like a network issue then. How is the performance if you import the data using SSIS (Import/Export Wizard) instead of linked servers?

Comment: I have tried but I cannot connect to these two servers in Source or destination of (Import/Export wizard). What is more strange is when I run the query locally its taking 10s but when I run it though linked server from another server (all the table starts with linked server.DB.dbo.table) its taking 0 sec!!!!